Numpy error when reading Hdf5 file (Encountered in Numpy version 2.0.0)
I am using Python version 3.10.12. The following error was encountered when I was trying to read a hdf5 file using pandas
(I am using Numpy version 2.0.0)
The error is
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 2
      1 file_path = 'GOLD_XYZ_OSC.0001_1024.hdf5'
----> 2 df=pd.read_hdf(file_path)
      3 # modulation_classes = json.load(open("classes-fixed.json", 'r'))
      4 
      5 # data=h5py.File(file_path,'r')

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py:426, in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, errors, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, **kwargs)
    423 if not exists:
    424     raise FileNotFoundError(f"File {path_or_buf} does not exist")
--> 426 store = HDFStore(path_or_buf, mode=mode, errors=errors, **kwargs)
    427 # can't auto open/close if we are using an iterator
    428 # so delegate to the iterator
    429 auto_close = True

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py:566, in HDFStore.__init__(self, path, mode, complevel, complib, fletcher32, **kwargs)
    563 if "format" in kwargs:
    564     raise ValueError("format is not a defined argument for HDFStore")
--> 566 tables = import_optional_dependency("tables")
    568 if complib is not None and complib not in tables.filters.all_complibs:
    569     raise ValueError(
    570         f"complib only supports {tables.filters.all_complibs} compression."
    571     )
...
     48 hdf5_version = _get_hdf5_version()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.pyx:1, in init tables.utilsextension()

ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

The code which I wrote which is causing this error is
file_path = 'GOLD_XYZ_OSC.0001_1024.hdf5'
df=pd.read_hdf(file_path)
I tried looking online but it seems this issue is not there yet.
For now, i just tried on reading the documentation and changing the version of pandas

numpy 2.0 is new, and many packages haven't been updated to march.  Try to use an earlier numpy like 1.26
